# Do you own chametz bought on credit?

Tags: halacha, passover, transactions, chametz-leaven

On Hol Hamo'ed, someone purchases chametz on-line using a credit card. The order was processed during Hol Hamo'ed, but will arrive at the person's home after Pesach is over. The credit card payment is not due until after Pesach.

Has this person possessed chametz during Pesach? Is chametz owned only when it is physically present in your premises? Or, even if not, is the fact that you charged it and it is ready to be delivered mean that you own it even if you don't have it? Or do you not own it at all because the bill hasn't yet been paid or doesn't need to be paid until later?

What if prior to it being delivered you cancelled the order?

Comment: What Kinyan has anyone done? You didn't pick up the object, and you didn't give him any money.

Comment: Would it matter if one used a debit card where the amount was paid but not yet delivered?

Comment: @DoubleAA It's possible that the bill of sale operates as a shtar for the purposes of effectuating a transfer. There would be no distinction between debit and credit in any case, one is just an obligation to a third party loan for the purchase.

Comment: @DoubleAA Isn't there a _kinyan mid'rabanan_ of "whatever standard business practice is" (though I forget what it's called)?

Comment: I think this can be generalized to "When does someone acquire an online purchase paid for with a credit card?"

Comment: @Daniel slightly different, perhaps, because in this case the purchaser explicitly doesn't ***WANT*** there to be a kinyan until the object reaches his house.

Comment: @msh210 I think you are thinking of Situmta.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky - Just jumping in - correct assumption.

Comment: see the book headlines by dovid lichtenstein he has a chapter on this question